# Running AML in Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.0, arcinfo-workstation, aml

I am trying to run an AML in a python program I am writing and haven't been having much luck figuring out the correct way to run the AML.

The AML requires ArcInfo Workstation to be from the GRID prompt.

Any tips? I am only a novice in ArcInfo Workstation.

I'm running ArcMap 10.0

Comment: See this old Esri forums post: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=254659

Comment: This may produce some unexpected results! To deal with large data issues ESRI created a "new" grid format that workstation will operate on but often produces dubious results. Perhaps, you should breakdown the raster operations in the AML and translate them to the current raster algebra syntax. Unless you are operating on the old coverage format I see no reason to be calling an AML. The "grid mode" that you are referring to is a module in Workstation and can be invoked using the "grid" command from the arc prompt. You can put this as the first line in the AML.

Comment: If you post the AML code the forum may be able to help translate to more current syntax or aim you to a already translated version. Most of my AML's have been translated to Python.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your comments. I converted the more simple aml's into python. Some of my aml's are much more complex and not worth the time to convert into python. I have been running the aml's in workstation no problem, I was just hoping I could find an easy way to run the aml's through python code I currently have. It's not much of a problem if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

From the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000010000000) (10.0 doesn't load for me):

**Update the system registry:**

- Browse to ArcToolbox\Scripts subfolder under your ArcGIS install.
- Double-click the file RegisterAmlAsExecutable.reg.
- Click Yes to add this information to the registry.

**Create a script tool that runs an AML file:**

- From within ArcGIS, right-click a folder or geodatabase and click New > Toolbox.
- Right-click the toolbox created in the previous step, click Add > Script. This starts the Add Script wizard.
- Name and describe the new script tool and click Next.
- Browse to the location of the AML file and click Next.
- Set up the input and output parameters and options and click Finish.

<s>AML is slowly being phased out in favor of ArcPy, however.</s>
I was in Kindergarten when AML was last reccomended. And now I'm a junior in college.

Comment: Slowly being phased out?!? :)  AML hasn't been recommended since 1999 with the release of 8.0, or even more conservatively since 2004 with the release of 9.0 and GP/ModelBuilder! (although I do realize there are still a lot of legacy Workstation applications & users out there)

Comment: Haha, honestly I didn't much about AML was until I Googled it today.

Comment: Well, I guess that's just embarrassing for us "old-schoolers" who had a love/hate relationship with it.  Just feel fortunate you haven't had to go through the AML, Avenue, VBA migration and are learning Python/ArcPy (although, the similarities are strikingly close now that arcpy.mapping has come along).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I got that far, but I guess my problem is getting the aml syntax down to make python open workstation, go into grid mode and run aml's that I have already created. Does that make sense?

Comment: Kindergarten, ouch! I kinda miss Workstation Arc/Info and AML. Particularly, the level of vector and individual raster cell access that you had.

Comment: @matt Well as I'm sure you've noticed, I don't know anything about AML. My knowledge doesn't extend beyond actually calling it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you certainly can create a script tool but personally I hate creating and maintaining a separate file (especially one that I can't edit in a text editor.)

You can call "arc" from Python directly and bypass that separate file. My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess
amlfile = "helloworld.aml"
args = ["c:/arcgis/arcexe9x/bin/arc", "&r " + amlfile]
p = subprocess.check_output(args)
print("AML %s said:" % amlfile)
print(p)
```

My output is this. (I don't even know enough to write a proper "Hello, World" in AML, I use other people's AML! I pasted some code into a file to test.)

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

* HelloWorld.aml *  Usage: &run helloworld.aml
Submitting command to Operating System ...
Submitting command to Operating System ...

Hello World
```

I have never used GRID but I presume you can start it running in an AML file? You could create the necessary AML file on the fly... this might work. It creates a file "wrapper.aml", puts the grid command into it, then a command
to run the amlfile, then sends wrapper.aml to arc.

```
import subprocess
wrapper="wrapper.aml"
with open(wrapper, "w") as fp:
  fp.write("GRID\n&RUN " + amlfile + "\n")
args = ["c:/arcgis/arcexe9x/bin/arc", "&r " + wrapper]
p = subprocess.check_output(args)
print("AML %s said:" % amlfile)
print(p)
```

In my example I used a complete path to "arc.exe" so that I don't need to modify the registry. If you have already put it into your registry you could just use "arc" as the first element of the "args" array.