# AML routines and python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcinfo-workstation, aml

I´m trying to use some AML files in ArcMap 10, but I have noticed that this option is not available for this version.

Does anyone know or tried to "translate" the aml sequences to another language for example python? or another application like QGIS or SAGA.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/how-to-run-an-aml-in-python) helpful.

Comment: If you have an ArcInfo license, why not install and use ArcInfo workstation?

Comment: I just spent 9 months rewriting 16 fairly complex AML scripts into Python. Please shoot me.

Answer (score 3):

[This reference in the ArcGIS help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000011000000.htm) is the closest you'll get. There is no automatic translator out there.

Answer (score 1):

AML is a proprietary algorithmic language of ESRI (as the late Avenue...).
Python, QGIS or SAGA are free.
So if ESRI does not want to "open" AML, nothing to do.

Their policy is rather to offer [Python equivalents to AML functions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000011000000), but for ArcPy and not for pure Python.

The solution is:

- a good knowledge of AML macros
- a good knowledge of Python (an not ArcPy only)
- try to find processings in Python equivalent to the AML Macro